# javafx draw concurrent into a number of canvases

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a gridpane with three columns (name, amount, position) and ~20 row (A, B, C, ...). In the third column I draw a stroke for every timestamp in list for that row. In the function I only iterate over the list and convert the timestamp into the position. This is how it looks right now.

```
for (int row = 0; row < timestamps.size(); row++)
{
    drawTimestamps(timestamps.get(row), duration, canvas, row);
}
```

Now since the recording I want to display can be relative long this can take some time. To draw the positions faster I thought about drawing all rows concurrent.
I've tried to do it with an AnimationTimer but this hasn't worked as planned (I think I did it wrong). Would this even be a way to draw a number of rows concurrent or is there a different approach that would do it faster?

```
    for (int row = 0; row < timestamps.size(); row++)
    {
        DrawTimer dt = new DrawTimer(timestamps.get(row), duration, canvas, row);
        dt.start();
    }


    private class DrawTimer extends AnimationTimer
    {
        private List<long> timeStamps;
        private int duration;
        private Canvas canvas;
        private int row;

        public DrawTimer(List<Long> timestamps, int duration, Canvas canvas, int row)
        {
            this.timestamps = timestamps;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.row = row;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(long now)
        {
            drawTimeStamps(timestamps, duration, canvas, row);
            stop();
        }
    }

    private void drawTimestamps(List<Long> timestamps, int duration, Canvas canvas, int row)
    {
        double width = canvas.getWidth();
        double height = canvas.getHeight();

        final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);
        for (long timestamp : timestamps)
        {
            double timestampPosition = timestamp * 1d / duration;
            gc.strokeLine(width * timestampPosition, height - height / 2, width * timestampPosition,
                height);
        }
    }
```

This is how It looks when the values are drawn into the canvas. Now every stroke Is a timestamp and this recording is ~7days long. The second column diplays how many timestamps there are.

[image: gridpane with timestamps]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I knew I forgot something. I added the draw function and an example of how it looks when its drawn

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;) Wondering what's so difficult to understand on that page ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "concurrent" here. Ultimately, all rendering must happen on the FX thread. You could look into [`ParallelTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html) to see if that fits your needs.

Comment: Right now I draw all values in row A, then B, then C and so on. If it is possible, I would like to draw all values in row A, B, C, ...  concurrent. Row B doesn't need to wait for row A to finish, row C doesn't need to wait for A, B, ... .

Comment: Try building a `Timeline` for each `Canvas` and then put all the `Timeline`s in a `ParallelTransition`.